# Randomly broken files from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I host my software installers on S3 and distribute them through CloudFront. Had couple complaints of broken files from customers. Problems appeared the same night.

My files are DMG disc images. Amazon sever status shows no incidents for May 10.

First customer got a "not recognised" error from Finder when trying to open it. Another one got a zero byte file and one .part file.

Any ideas what can be wrong?